# Object Reference Exception In Finally Block

Tags: exception, c#-3.0

Hi i have a following method.

```
public bool IsTableExist(string tableName)
    {
        try
        {

            if (Utility.Utility.CreatedTable.Contains(tableName.ToLower()))
                return true;
            else
            {
                _dataAccess.openconnection();
                if (!_dataAccess.isTableExist(tableName))
                    return false;
                Utility.Utility.CreatedTable.Add(tableName.ToLower());
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.WriteLogFile("QueryBuilder", "IsTableExist", ex.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {
             _dataAccess.closeconnection();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Here i am getting fllowing exception:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at DataAccessLayer.DataAccess.closeconnection()
at QueryBuilder.QueryBuilder.IsTableExist(String tableName)
at ObjectFilling.BusinessLogic.GetDataTypeForAllTags(DataTable tagDetails)
```

How to resolve the exception.I have openconnection() and closeconnection() methods which are used for communicating with the database.The exception is thrown in finally block when the `closeconnection()` method is called but `openconnection()` was not called.openconnectio() will be called only when the code reaches else block. Can i use bool variable in the else block to notify the finally block when to call closeconnection.Or is there any other way code can be modified so that the exception does not occur.
please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool isOpen = false; 
try 
 {  
   _dataAccess.openconnection(); 
   isOpen = true; 
 } 
 finally 
 { 
  if (isOpen) 
  _dataAccess.closeconnection(); 
 }
```

I found this as the working solution.Any further ideas would be welcomed.In this case bool variable will be set when the connection is opened.